# how to fill remaining empty columns in css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 5 columns. In the picture, I've demonstrated that when columns 1, 2 and 5 are "filled", I want to place an item in the remaining columns 3 and 4.

I never know what columns are "occupied", so the code should be flexible (first empty to last empty).

[image]

Comment: what are you filling with? is it some style or an element?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph a Div element, which will be styled to fit in the grid

Comment: can you show us your HTML structure and how you dispatch your element in the grid. are the holes emty elements or just missing element in the grid, is the hole supposed to be refilled with a single element for each cell grid or is it a single element to span through adjacent holes ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I'm implementing a Row/Col system. code is here: https://github.com/lundbeckconsulting/Creator/blob/master/STYLE/Layout/_Row.scss . I want to add a col-md tag that fills all columns from f.ex. col-md-3 to col-md-2. the col-md should then fill columns 4 to 7 (col-md-3 / col-md / col-md-2). does that make sense?

Comment: okay, not too sure, but i guess you need to have the first empty div to be spanning till the last. CSS (even generated through a processor) cannot select a previous sibbling. here is what i understand from what you try to do : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBBbXwa (if the html code is generated on server side, best is to handle this from there).

Answer (score 3):

**Using CSS** use the `:empty` pseudo-class to check if an element is empty.

**Using JS** use `innerHTML == ''` to check if the element is empty.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.grid div').forEach(e => {
  if (e.innerHTML == '') {
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.grid div {
  background: green;
}

.grid div:empty {
  background: Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! is it possible to alter the code to implement range? so that one div can span from first empty to last empty using grid-column?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by a range? like, this now would take all cells in the grid, unless you want to have some conditions to the querySelector

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm overthinking it. I'll try to implement your solution. thanks!

Comment: please feel free to accept the solution if it has worked.